# Maximal distance from two convex hulls in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$, $\{y_n\}$ be finite sets of points in Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Denote their convex hulls by $C \subset X$ and $D \subset Y$.
Under what conditions may we claim that
$$\sup_{x \in X, y \in Y} \|x - y\| = \|x_i - y_j\|$$
for some $x_i, y_j$?

In Euclidean space, this holds by a simple application of Lagrange multipliers. But I am not sure about how to proceed in the general setting of Banach spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This should follow from the general fact that a continuous convex function on a compact convex set (in your case: $K= C\times D$, $f(x,y)=\|x-y\|$) achieves its maximum at *extreme points*. This is a standard and very useful fact in what is called convex optimization.